# Facebook reads wrong title and description from my doman?

Tags: facebook, wordpress, parsing, title

This is my [domain](http://studioedno.com)

[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmyRh.jpg) is what facebook reads when I share it

If i share the link with the index.php fully typed as that  studioedno.com/index.php there is no problem
My domain went to new hosting lately and I don't even have that info there... is facebook caching domain info somehow? I dunno what to do, any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Facebook caches for a good amount of time (about 24 hours, in my experience).

You can clear the cache and get useful debug info at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug.

Answer (score 1):

You should use open graph tags to specify how you want your site to appear when shared.  There are various plugins that can help you with this, just search open graph in the wordpress repository.

Comment: Thank you, I'll make my research about open graph... and for the others who experience same kind of problem here is what facebook offers http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug